# How to determine depth of foundation on existing detached garage

Tags: foundation

I have a house that was built in 1954 in a suburb of Chicago with a detached garage and am considering converting it to a living space.  To determine depth of foundation and whether footers are in place, we need to excavate next to the foundation until we find the footers or bottom of the foundation.

What is the best way to do this?  I have a bid from a foundation repair firm for $650 to dig it out, but that seems expensive.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: hire a local kid to dig the hole?

Answer (score 1):

You only need check one location. As I remember a 32" frost line, so a 3 ft hole with a shovel does not sound like much of a job. I hand dug a pond 3' deep X 11' long X 6' wide , not that big a deal. Worth getting a fiberglas handle shovel if you don't have one. For a small hole like that a "clam shell" post hole digger may be helpful.

Comment: 500$ for the paper work 100$ for the truck and tools to arrive on site and 50$ max for a laborer to dig the hole. Yes it sounds silly but even paying 15$ per hour for un skilled labor you can get a fair sized hole dug in 3 hours. +